# How to store different version of data in a relational database?

Tags: mysql, sql, relational-database

Here is the example, for example, I have a table called `Profile`, and have different columns like:

```
id, firstName, secondName, address
```

typically, I create a profile, full in the information, and the database will become something like this:

```
 1| Ted | WONG | Hong Kong |
```

after that, I may update the data, like this

```
 1| Ted | WONG | US |
```

the data `Hong Kong` will be changed by an `UPDATE` SQL command, and I lose track of previous data. So, is there any way to let the database keep track of previous data and maintain the current information? Thanks.

Comment: I'd hope it was changed through `UPDATE` rather than `ALTER` - what database are you using?

Comment: you are right, I just type wrong. MySQL.

Comment: I've added that tag and deleted my answer, since I don't think it would work against MySQL.

Answer (score 3):

Add a version number column that you increase with each update but retain the same id. Then when retrieving the latest row for a given id you need to do a

```
where versionNo = (select max(versionNo) from table where id = <outerTableAliasOrVariable>.id)
```

Comment: Performing a max(verionNo) on every query can really bog down performance when you get a lot of data.  I do something similar except I prefer to make Version 0 the latest and archive all the data to Version X before any updates.  It makes querying much simpler.

Answer (score 2):

Add a "Version" column as the first column of every table that you want to track versions, and their child tables.  The column should be added to your clustered primary key as the first column.   The current version should always have Version=0 to make writing your queries easier, and not require searching for MAX(version) on every query.  Make sure that all child tables also contain the Version column and reference it in their foreign keys.  Before an update, copy Version=0 data from ALL related tables to Version=1.  The next update would copy to Version=2 and so forth.  Eventually you would have the oldest data in Version=1, the latest in Version=0 and the newest in Version=X.  This way you can make complicated database schemas, control data versions and be able to completely roll back data to a historical version by copying data from Version=X to Version=0.

In your case, your new table structure would be...

**Version, id, firstName, secondName, address (PK- VersionId, id)**

If you had a child table, like a transaction table, it would look like this...

**Version, id, TransactionId, Amount (PK- VersionId, id, TransactionId)**

I've used this method for maintaining data versions without having to make extra tables to support it.

Answer (score 1):

This can be achieved by storing all historical data and having a `group` column:

```
id, firstname,secondname, address, group
```

then when you update the data you never `ALTER` it, you simply add a new revision.

So, your table will look like the following:

```
1, Ted, Wong, Hong Kong, 1
2, Ted, Wong, US, 1
```

So to retrieve the current (or last) revisions you need to select the appropriate revision:

```
SELECT TOP 1 * FROM <table> WHERE Group = 1 ORDER BY id DESC
```

Comment: but I use the id as a key to make relationship with other table, for example, I have a user table with profile_id, if I do in this way, when I have a new version, my profile table id is changed, and the user table's profile_id is point to a not update data.

Comment: Yes correct, so i that case you need to rationalize you database structure better. Pick the columns that will NOT change and stick them in the first table. Then you can put the profile data in another table and use a scheme similar to mine or KAJ's and perform the join on the data using the latest revision or version number